# How do I pin the SSL certificate in an Ionic React application

Tags: react-native, ssl, ionic-framework

I need to test a self signed certificate with my ionic react app, and I am unable to find a way to configure the certificate in the app? I spent two days searching for answers online, but all the answers that I got were for angular apps, and the ones I could find for Ionic React didn't work for me. I tried using many solutions that I found on the ionic forms and on SO portal.

**First Approach**

Below is a set of commands I tried to configure the SSL certificate:

```
ionic config set -g ssl.cafile /ssl/ca.crt
ionic config set -g ssl.certfile /ssl/client.crt
ionic config set -g ssl.keyfile /ssl/client_key.pem
```

**Second Approach**

I also tried configuring it in the config file as below:

```js
{
  "name": "xyzname",
  "integrations": {
    "capacitor": {}
  },
  "options": {
    "browserTarget": "app:build",
    "ssl": true,
    "sslKey": "./ssl/server.key",
    "sslCert": "./ssl/server.crt"
  },
  "type": "react"
}
```

These are only two of the many approaches I tried.

Note: The certificate names that I used in the later try (config file) are different as I regenerated the certificates.